# Installing web2py on windows xp

Tags: cygwin, web2py

How does one install web2py on Windows XP using cygwin? I've just installed cygwin and downloaded web2py in cygwin using

```
curl -O http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_src.zip
```

but when I try to unzip it using

```
unzip web2py_src.zip
```

it doesn't work (returns the error: `-bash: unzip: command not found`)

What do I do?

Comment: You need to add the 'unzip' package to your cygwin installation: http://cygwin.com/packages/unzip/ or http://mirrors.syringanetworks.net/cygwin/release/unzip/

Comment: in tried but am still having issues:

Comment: user@user-4e822dccb0 ~
$ curl -O http://cygwin.com/packages/unzip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   318  100   318    0     0    281      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  4968

user@user-4e822dccb0 ~
$ unzip web2py_src.zip
-bash: unzip: command not found

Comment: please, how do i download the unzip package?

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to open web2py from cygwin command prompt. Instead I used Windows CMD (after a day's crash course on it) and have been able to open web2py from the WCMD. I simply cd'd to the directory web2py was (I moved it from Downloads to drive C), then ran the -S projectname command, and voila, my project has been created and I'm able to work from the WCMD.Please I may be asking more questions as my journey progresses. Thanks to Regexident for your swift attempt to help!